# openssl enc -d -base64 command returns empty file

Tags: file, openssl, base64, decoding

When I use this OpenSSL command line :

> openssl enc -d  -base64 -in g.b64 -out dilo.txt

to decode a simple base64 to plaintext , I get an empty dilo.txt file .

These are the details :[image]

Then

[image]

Then I get an empty dilo.txt file:

[image]